# With Cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport can be hidden the scroll bar?

Tags: css, angular

I want to hide the scroll bar in my cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport so this is my html:

```
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport appendOnly itemSize="20"  class="friends-list" >
      <div *ngFor="let componente of componentes">
        <app-friend></app-friend>
      </div>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

and my css where I try to hide the bar is this:

```
cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport{
   scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

This cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport is in a div and the only thing that gives this div is height and width, I look in forums and the solution is the given above but it doesn't work, for a better understanding let my show you what I want to hide:

[image]

That little bar on the right side, I try to use overflow hidden on the father div and make larger the width but with this doesn't work the virtual scroll view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it by using this in `friends-list`:

```
.example-viewport {
  /*Other styles.....*/
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.example-viewport::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Hide scrollbar on Firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* Hide scrollbar on IE and Edge */
    overflow: -webkit-hidden-scrollbar; /* Hide scrollbar on Chrome, Safari, 
    and newer versions of Edge */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your global styles.css or styles.scss you can add the following code
`::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }`

if you want to remove some white spaces generated by angular use this in global styles

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
```

}